# Annotating datasource for helper class

Tags: jdbc, annotations, ejb-3.0

I am declaring a resource dependency in my MDB ,that would be used by a helper class within.

```
@MessageDriven(name = "BazaarBillingMDB", mappedName = "jms/EJB3Queue", activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationName", propertyValue = "jms/EJB3Queue") }
)
@Resource(name="EJB3Source",mappedName="jdbc/EJB3Source",type=javax.sql.DataSource.class)
public class BazaarBillingMDB implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            TextMessage msg = (TextMessage) message;
            String order = (String) msg.getText();
            try {
                bazaarhelper helper=new bazaarhelper();
                helper.insertBilling(order);
            } 
....
}
```

And the helper class(bazaarhelper) tries to get a handle to this datasource:

```
try {
            context=new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/EJB3Source");
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
```

However,I  am always facing a NamingException when the helper class tries to get a handle to the datasource.
This datasource works fine when injected as a resource in another EJB though.
What needs to be done to get the resource to be reachable by the helper class?

Comment: Please include printStackTrace in your post, if possible include the helper class too.

Comment: I'm curious: why are you instantiating a helper class instead of making it an EJB and injecting it into your MDB?